# Different Target .Net Framework on each C# Project

Tags: c#, linq

is it ok if i have this **X project** using .net2.0, and that **X project** is calling **Y project** which is using .net3.5.. i got customized buttons in **Y project** and im using that button in **X project** also, there's a method in **Y project** that has LINQ and **X project** is calling that method... i cant test it because i installed the latest .net framework.. :)

this is my code in project that has the .net3.5

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetDriveType(string lpRootPathName);        

    public enum DriveType : int
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        NoRoot = 1,
        Removable = 2,
        Localdisk = 3,
        Network = 4,
        CD = 5,
        RAMDrive = 6
    }
    var selectedDrives = from s in Environment.GetLogicalDrives() where Enum.GetName(typeof(DriveType), GetDriveType(s)).Equals(DriveType.Removable) select s;
        foreach (String drives in selectedDrives)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(drives);

        }
```

correct also the LINQ statement if i did it wrong.. :)

Comment: will a string (`GetName`) *ever* equal an int/enum ? I'm thinking: not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 3.5 framework is not installed on the machine that executes this, it will fail as `System.Linq.dll` won't exist. You *can* use LINQBridge with .NET 2.0 and C# 3.0 (which will give you access to a re-implementation of LINQ-to-Objects) but in reality it may be easier to get the client to upgrade. 2.0 is pretty old now.

Alternatively... if all you need is a `where`, there are easier routes. For example:

```
foreach (String drives in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
{
    if(!Enum.GetName(typeof(DriveType), GetDriveType(s))
        .Equals(DriveType.Removable))
    {
        continue;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(drives);
}
```

Comment: but in the case of using linq, is code in my question is also working?

Comment: @vrynxzent allow me to repeat: it depends on whether the 3.5 framework is installed on the machine that executes it. If yes: yes. If no: no.

Answer (score 0):

A .NET 2.0 project cannot call a method in a .NET 3.5 project.

Comment: Actually, it can. Especially if you compile in VS2008 which is less fussy. Or use reflection. Or various other things. The key question is: "does the target machine have .NET 3.5?"

Comment: I hesitated to post the answer after I typed it.  I decided to, hoping someone would post something similar to what you did (w/ details, like those you mentioned, that I didn't have the knowledge to anticipate).  A better answer would have said that trying to call a .NET 3.5 method from a .NET 2.0 project might not be advisable for someone new to .NET (or programming in general).

Comment: Even if the target machine doesn't have .NET 3.5, a .NET 2.0 project can use .NET 3.5 stuff if it includes the proper dlls from .NET 3.5, though actually taking advantage of this is potentially a violation of a license and definitely bad practice.  I don't think the 3.5 dlls are supposed to be redistributed piecemeal.  Keep in Mind that .Net 2.0 and .NET 3.5 use the same CLR.